# How is `toString` in `scala.Enumeration$Value` implemented?

Tags: scala, enumeration

I have an enum `Fruit` defined as:

```
object Fruit extends Enumeration {
  val Apple, Banana, Cherry = Value
}
```

Now printing values of this enum, on Scala 2.7.x gives:

```
scala> Fruit foreach println
line1$object$$iw$$iw$Fruit(0)
line1$object$$iw$$iw$Fruit(1)
line1$object$$iw$$iw$Fruit(2)
```

However the same operation on Scala 2.8 gives:

```
scala> Fruit foreach println       
warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
Apple
Banana
Cherry
```

My question is:

How is the method `toString` in `Enumeration` in Scala 2.8 implemented? I tried looking into the source of `Enumeration` but couldn't understand anything.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation is based on the Java reflection API.

If you define val for the enum values:

```
object Fruit extends Enumeration {
  val Apple, Banana, Cherry = Value
}
```

There are methods for the val in the class Fruit:

```
scala> Fruit.getClass.getMethods filter (_.getName.contains("Apple")) foreach println

public scala.Enumeration$Value line10$object$$iw$$iw$Fruit$.Apple()
```

`toString` calls `Enumeration.this.nameOf(i)` if the name is not explicitly set. This method will try to find all methods in the enumeration class returning `Value` instances.

```
val methods = getClass.getMethods
for (m <- methods
    if (classOf[Value].isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType) &&
    !java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isFinal(m.getModifiers) &&
    m.getParameterTypes.isEmpty &&
    isValDef(m)))
```

These are the methods of the Fruit class.

It then takes the name of the methods and the ids of enum values to build a map `id -> name` and retrieves the name from the map with the id of enum value.

```
val name = m.getName
// invoke method to obtain actual `Value` instance
val value = m.invoke(this)
// invoke `id` method
val idMeth = classOf[Val].getMethod("id")
val id: Int = idMeth.invoke(value).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer].intValue()
```

This implementation can be easily broken if you define a enum like this:

```
object X extends Enumeration {
    val Y = Value
}
object Fruit extends Enumeration {
    val x = X.Y
    val A,B,C = Value
}
```

This Fruit.value returns `object$Fruit.ValueSet(x, B, C)` not `object$Fruit.ValueSet(A, B, C)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.8.0.RC2 you can find the implementation of `toString` in the inner class `Val` in [line 273](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_RC2/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L273) of `Enumeration.scala`. The instances of `Val` are instantiated through the `Value` method in [line 192](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_RC2/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L192). Currently I don't understand how the names (`Apple, Banana, ...`) are extracted. May somebody can help out?